# Mutation Observer not working properly with Angular based website

Tags: javascript, dom, mutation-observers

I'm listening for child node insertions, it is working on first page instance, but when I open another page (identical), the mutation observer is not dispatching any mutations even though nodes are inserted.

I can see visually in Devtools, the nodes are appended, but mutation observer is not detecting those insertions.

This is strange behavior. I've already used mutation observer on different websites, and it works perfectly for me.

[image: screenshot]

```
const target = document.querySelector("#cards-list-loads");

observer = new MutationObserver(searchWatcher);
observer.observe(target, {childList: true, subtree: true});
console.log('Observer attached');
```

Comment: It usually means the ancestor element is entirely replaced. You need to observe a node higher in the tree than that ancestor e.g. `document` for maximum reliability as all the other nodes can be replaced.

Comment: No the ancestor element is not replaced, I checked this in devtools, only the childs are appending.

Comment: Devtools won't show it differently so this is something you should actually try before dismissing.

Comment: What wOxxOm said appears to be true. I was able to verify it using the following code: `document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<div></div>'); setTimeout(() => { document.body.children[0].remove(); document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<div>abc</div>');}, 5000)`. The code inserts a `div` element a right after the body tag and then removes it and places another `div` tag with some content into the same place.

Comment: You could try observing `document.body` to see if there are any changes. I'm having a similar problem where I cannot see modifications that Angular is making to a web site.

Comment: yes @wOxxOm your idea worked :). Thanks